# Java differentiate between menu click and accelerator

Tags: java, swing, menu, accelerator

I have menu items with an accelerators. I would like to detect when a menu item was clicked as opposed to executed using accelerator. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Alexander.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can listen for MouseEVents and Actions, you can also just inspect the modifiers of the ActionEvent and see if a key was involved in the event or not.  That way, you only have one listener to deal with...

Comment: It is possible that a user is pressing a modifier while clicking the menu item. But I think this is close enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a mouse click will fire off a MouseEvent and an Action.  An accelerator will only fire off an action.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the key-info in the ActionEvent with the Action#ACCELERATOR_KEY key-value pair, which should be able to distinguish between a user clicking while holding a random/modifier key, and the actual accelerator key combination